# Help with math in C

Tags: c, math

I need to know how to make this ignore the number 0 when 0 is input so that the program does not exit when 0 is input.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int input = 0, previous = 0;


    do {
        previous = input;
        printf("Input Number");
        scanf("%d", &input);
    } while( input!= previous*2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to never exit if they enter zero, or just not on the first try? It looks to me like it will exit the first time on `0`, or later on if `0` is entered twice in a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    #include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int input = 0, previous = 0;


    do {
        previous = input;
        printf("Input Number");
        scanf("%d", &input);
    } while( input == 0 || input!= previous*2 );

    return 0;
}
```

I added an OR operator, that means that if input is equal to 0, then it will still continue, but, if it is not 0, and the second condition is satisfied, it will break the loop and exit.

Comment: Cool works great. I was looking up what the ! is and I kind of dont get what it is really for and also what is the two || lines for? Like how can I read the while line in maybe like a plain english way?

Comment: while input equals 0 or(||) input is not equal to (previous times 2)

Answer (score 2):

Pick a different value for `previous`. Try `INT_MAX >> 1` from limits.h.

Comment: Or you could probably just get away with not initializing it.

Comment: redEvo: that's dangerous, some systems my initialize to 0 by default.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int input = 0, previous = 0;

    do {
        previous = input;
        printf("Input Number");
        scanf("%d", &input);
    } while( input!= previous*2 || input==0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

while( input == 0 || input!= previous*2 ) in plain english this reads: while input equals zero or input is not equal to twice the previous.  || is a logical or operation, and != (which was in your original code by the way) means not equal to.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation helps alot. I thought == means equals to?

Comment: yes, you could write that same thing while input is equal to zero or input is not equal to twice the previous. so broken down: (input==0 [input is equal to zero] ||[or] inupt!=previous*2[input not equal to previous times 2]